# javascript - select entire string on doubleclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm passing data into my browser from a django backend that may contains spaces as `{{ string }}` such as `This is the sentence` or `H3ll0W0!rd`.  When doing a doubleclick I want to be able to select the entire sentence or string so that it can be copied.

Example of the HTML would be

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Book Title</th>
                <th>Book Code</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for b in books %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ b.title }}</td>
                <td>{{ b.code}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you know when to begin or end it? You provided 2 very different examples. Are you using any frameworks?

Comment: Can we assume the text in the page is wrapped in its own element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an example. To define which text can be selected, just put it inside a `p` tag. Take a look:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('p').dblclick(function(e){

        $(this).selectText();
        // If you want, here you can also copy the text.
        e.preventDefault();

    });

});

jQuery.fn.selectText = function(){
    this.find('input').each(function() {
        if($(this).prev().length == 0 || !$(this).prev().hasClass('p_copy')) { 
            $('<p class="p_copy" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1;"></p>').insertBefore($(this));
        }
        $(this).prev().html($(this).val());
    });
    var doc = document;
    var element = this[0];
    console.log(this, element);
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(element);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();        
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
This is a text <p>example another one</p> bla bla bla bla <br>
Some <p>text text text</p> x x x text
```

Js Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mdn403wj/

Here there is an exemple with "how to select a div content text".

[Use jQuery select() to select contents of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975707/use-jquery-select-to-select-contents-of-a-div)

Is this your question?

Answer (score 6):

You could use a double click listener like so:

```js
document.getElementById('test').ondblclick = function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(this);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
};
```

```html
<p id="test">Here is some text</p>
```

Comment: Read again, the question **is** about text highlighting.

Comment: Haha, that's pretty much exactly [what I was about to post](http://jsfiddle.net/7o7z8cbf/). As you can see, it only works on elements where there is only text. I would also call `event.preventDefault` to make sure the browser doesn't deselect it automatically afterward, but it seems to work just fine without it.

Comment: Very true, browser seems to handle it but better to be safe than sorry. I've edited my answer, thanks :)