# Auto select text when clicked

Tags: jquery, select

I've made a div with some dummytext in it and I want all the dummytext to be selected when clicked on the div (instead of three clicks to select all, I want one). I've got the correct code to catch the mouseclick, but I can't find the right code to select the text.

I tested the first part of the code with an alert and it worked.

```
<div id="tekstveld>
dummytext with two paragraphs
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tekstveld').on('click', function(e){
    //some code to autoselect all the text in the div, I don't know })
})
```

I'm using Jquery 3.5.1.

Edit: answer found:

Thanks, as natel said. I had to change the div to a input text (same as YouTube with the option to embed code).

HTML:

```
<input readonly type="text" id="tekstveld" value="Click Here To Copy This Text to Clipboard" readonly>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tekstveld').on('click', function(e){
    this.select();});})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use jQuery select() to select contents of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975707/use-jquery-select-to-select-contents-of-a-div)

Comment: Do you only want the text to be selected?  Or, do you also want it to copy to the clipboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can the text be inside of an input like this or do you need the text inside of a div?
You can replace "Click Here To Copy This Text to Clipboard" with anything you want like such as "dummytext with two paragraphs"

```js
$(function() {
  $('.copy-text-to-clipboard input').click(function() {
        $(this).focus();
        $(this).select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        $(".copied").text("Copied the text to clipboard").show().fadeOut(3000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class='copied text'></div>
  <div class="copy-text-to-clipboard">
    <input readonly type="text" value="Click Here To Copy This Text to Clipboard" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `this.select()` and see if it works.

Here is a code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
$('input').on('click', function(e){
  this.select();
})

});
```

```css
input{
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border:none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter whatever you like">
```